# How to get ref names with git log --pretty=format:"...."? %d shows refs, but all in same color

Tags: git, git-log

I'm trying to get a customized git log listing using --pretty=format:"....", but can't seem to find out how get the *ref names* colored as in `git log --oneline`. This is my log command so far:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%Creset %d %ci (%cr)%n    ==> %s%n"
```

It displays all I want, except for the coloring of the refs:

[image]

Is there a way to get the refs printed in color such as in `git log --oneline`?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use of `%C` directives disables automatic colorization unless you re-enable it with `%C(auto)`.  You can just replace the `%Creset` part with `%C(auto)` (per testing).

So the final command for your case will be:

```sh
git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%C(auto) %d %ci (%cr)%n    ==> %s%n"
```